# Need a suggestion on building a DB in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem on building my db, that is I would like to create a DB for the following scenerio.

I have a group of people lets take 5 with one one admin. I have given a questions to the group Like how do you rate your self. and at same rate the others in your group. So each person in a group will rate himself and others and admin will rate for all the people so How I can draw the table. Please provide me your valuable suggestions.

What I have tried is I have created a table as below
This is table for one student(stud1) he will or himself and for others.

```
Stud1

Name  Q1 Q2 Q3
stud1 20 30 40
stud2 40 50 60
```

This is the table for another student(stud2)

```
    Stud2

    Name  Q1 Q2 Q3
    stud1 30 10 90
    stud2 80 100 35
```

Like the above table I  will for all the 6 students and for all the 8 questions.
Now from the table I will take avg of q1 or stud1 (20+30) (the values 20 from table one and  30 from table which is answered for student one or q1 and display a graph lets avg be 25 and what he rated himself that is 20. So by taking two values avg-25 and his own rating 30 I will display the graph.

The values I will post only the values from my android app.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing ... Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17084467/edit) to include what have tried so far and what you think is wrong with that schema. That will give others a starting point ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are lots of possible solutions.
Let me know your opinion about.. this one:

[image: DB Model]

But I suggest you to use your creativity and make your changes.
A group example should be "admin".
*Keywords on image above - UN = Unsigned, NN = Not Null, AI = Auto-Increment*

Answer (score 0):

Create a table named `users_tb` with these columns:

```
name :ID            type:INT     key:primary  attribute:Auto_increment 
name :rate          type INT     key:index
name :privilege     type:INT     size:1 (take 0 for user and 1 for admin)
```

Comment: No it is not working like that I have tried it. Because I will only post the values.